# Error in DF (*tmp*) replacement has 6678 rows, data has 6679. Using diff

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate SD of S&P 500 returns, but I am having a tough time creating a new column containing daily returns in my df, SPY, without an error. 
Essentially I want:

```
 SPY$returns <-(8/7/19 close price / 8/6/2019) - 1 ]
```

I have already tried some things, and I believe this will give me the correct values in the returns column, but I keep getting an error.

Here is the head of my data:

```
head(SPY)
# A tibble: 6 x 7
  Date       Open  High   Low Close `Adj Close`    Volume
  <chr>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>     <dbl>
1 8/7/2019   284.  289.  282.  288.        288. 135389300
2 8/6/2019   286.  288.  284.  288.        288. 120711700
3 8/5/2019   288.  288.  282.  284.        284. 178745400
4 8/2/2019   294.  294.  291.  293.        293. 116749700
5 8/1/2019   298.  301.  294.  295.        295. 142646600
6 7/31/2019  301.  301.  295.  297.        297. 104245200
```

```
SPY$returns <- diff(Close / Close[-length(Close)] - 1)
```

Here is the error message:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, returns, value = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  : 
  replacement has 6678 rows, data has 6679
In addition: Warning message:
In Close/Close[-length(Close)] :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Alternate explanation of my problem: I want to do [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEPYf.png) in R

Comment: can you try and explain in different words what you want here? I'm confused as to what you are trying to achieve. But you can't jsut write `Close`, you probably need `SPY$Close`

Comment: @RAB I added an image to the question above which is exactly what I would like to do in excel form. Having trouble creating this new column in R.  Thanks! P.S. adding SPY$Close did not help, the error message is the exact same as before.

Comment: so you always want to divide by the one after it? wither a for loop or a tidyverse solution is what you are after in that case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, transform you "Date"-column to date type:

```
SPY$Date <- lubridate::dmy(SPY$Date)
```

Then, arrange tibble w.r.t. Date and create return column:

```
SPY <- SPY %>% arrange(Date) %>% mutate(return = Close/dplyr::lag(Close)-1)
```